# Getting the next leafnode in a binary search tree using an iterator

Tags: java, iterator, nodes

I have some problems when it comes to the next()-method in my LeafNodeIterator-class. 
First of all a leaf node is a node with **no children** in a binary search tree.(Not sure if leafnode is the right english word for it...)

In the constructor I've moved my pointer *p* to the first leafnode using this method:

```
  private BladnodeIterator()  // constructor
{
  if(root == null) return;
  firstleafnode(root);
}

private void firstleafnode(Node<T> p)
{
    while(p != null)
    {
        if(p.left == null && p.right == null)
            return;

        p = nextInorder(p);
    }
}


The "nextInorder(p)"-method just moves p to the next Node in Inorder-order.
```

My question when it comes to the next()-method, which is supposed to return a leafnode-value, and move p to the next leafnode(or null if there are no more leafnodes), is how to code it? Either way I try it I end up doing it wrong.

My apologies if the question or code is unclear.

EDIT:
The code for the nextinorder-method:

```
    private static <T> Node<T> nextInorder(Node<T> p)
  {
      if(p.right != null) 
      {
          p = p.right;
          while(p.left != null)
          {
              p = p.left;
          }
          return p;
      }
      while(p != null)
      {
          if(p.parent != null && p.parent.left == p)
          {
              return p.parent;
          }
           p = p.parent;
      }
      return p;
  }
```

Comment: What is the code of nextInorder method ?

Comment: private static <T> Node<T> nextInorder(Node<T> p)
  {
      if(p.right != null) 
      {
          p = p.right;
          while(p.left != null)
          {
              p = p.left;
          }
          return p;
      }
      while(p != null)
      {
          if(p.parent != null && p.parent.venstre == p)
          {
              return p.parent;
          }
           p = p.parent;
      }
      return p;
  }